# Calc Column: Count when column1="x" and column2="y"

Tags: calculated-column

Within a list, I have two drop down choices. I want to create a calculated column(S) to count each combination of the two choices.

So if C1 can be a,b,or c,   and C2 can be x, y, or z.

count how many times each situation is picked
A-X, A-Y, A-Z, B-X, etc

EDIT: The end state, is to use this calculated value in a graph, so I need to be able to reference it in a graph web part. Right now, I'm using a table, which I populate manually by using the group-by method below.

Comment: Maybe you can create a Calculated Column that combines the two fields, Then use a Grouped By [Your Calculated Column] / Counted VIEW to display the counts. Calculated Formulas can only work on their own Item values, it does not have any awareness (or access to) of other Items in your List (Like Rows in an Excel sheet can)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out what Danny already posted. So credit to you Danny. It took my too long...

Here the explanation with picures. The result could look like this:

[image]

So create a calculated column and as formular you could use this:

```
[Dropdown1]&[Dropdown2]
```

That will give you the combination of your two columns.

Then create a view and as Danny already wrote use the "Group by" option to group your view with the calculated column. In my case, the column `Calculated`.

Those steps could give you a possible solution for your requirement.

Comment: That does help, although I'd want to use the data in a graph so something that allows me to call a # would be preferable.